# Move Certificates from Server to Remote Computer (MACS)

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-server, remote-desktop

So I am trying to push a certificate from a location (server) onto a remote mac computer so that then I can run a script that installs the certificates onto keychain and installs the application. Do you guys have any idea on how to get the certificate onto the other machine?

I have OS X Server set up and Apple Remote Desktop as well if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) provides a handy way to do this. It also happens to be nearly platform-independent (Windows requires Cygwin or similar).

Ex: from the Mac you want the certs on:

```
scp -r user@server:/path/to/cert/directory /where/you/want/the/certs
```

Note that the '-r' option works on entire directories, if you only want to work on the certs, not the directory containing them, you may ignore it.

Comment: Note: if you want to do this from the server, simply change the order of the arguments for the command.